# Is there a query that will select the transitive relationship between a table and a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

I have a stored procedure that, via a call in to a series of other stored procedures, eventually selects some data from a certain table. I know the name of this table, and that of the stored procedure, but the series of queries is too complicated to track down using SSMS. So, I would like to write a query to determine this. Here is what I've come up with thus far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name, s.name, t.name
FROM sys.sysdepends AS d
INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p 
ON d.id = p.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = d.depid
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s 
ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE p.name = 'MySprocName' 
AND t.name = 'MyTableName'
```

However, this only works for immediate dependencies, not transitive dependencies. Could this be modified to run recursively, or find the relationship with some other approach?

EDIT: I found that my question is a duplicate, just worded differently. [T-SQL: Show stored procedures related to tables, cyclically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407275/t-sql-show-stored-procedures-related-to-tables-cyclically). Closing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Show stored procedures related to tables, cyclically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407275/t-sql-show-stored-procedures-related-to-tables-cyclically)